# How to remove linebreaks from a DomDocument::saveHTML

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, line-breaks

I am using XPath to get some paragraphs from my DomDocument.
This works fine and returns me the desired data.

The problem is that when doing:

```
foreach ($paragraph->childNodes as $child) {
    $node .= $paragraph->ownerDocument->saveHTML($child);
}
```

If there is an initial line break, this will be keept, and I would like to get rid of all linebreaks.

I tryed:

```
$node = trim($node); // Does not work
```

Then:

```
$breaks = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$node = str_replace($breaks, " ", $node); // Doesn't work
```

I also tryed:

```
$paragraph->ownerDocument->formatOutput = false;
$paragraph->ownerDocument->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
```

Did not work.

Any Idea on how to get rid of those line breaks ?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the $node input:

```
&lt;b&gt;Keywords: &lt;/b&gt;marine fungus; sediment; anthranilic acid; &lt;i&gt;Penicillium&#13; paneum&lt;/i&gt;; cytotoxicity
```

Apparently, the problematic character is `&#13;` what is this special character ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it is the character `&#13;` that is causing te linebreak. I never heared about this special character, no idea how it is produced.

So basicaly, what I had to do is to replace it.

Answer (score 3):

```
$node = preg_replace(array('/\r/', '/\n/'), '', $node);
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: Can you share a sample input of $node ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try `preg_replace`

```
   $string =  preg_replace("#<br\s*/?>#i", "", $string);
```

or Try

```
preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $yourString);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, but no, the result is the same